# Closing a file powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that opens all pdf files in a folder, prints them, and then closes the files.  I have the first 2 parts working, however I can not find a way to close the files after.  I've done some google searching but found nothing.  I'm new to powershell so if there is a better way to doing this please let me know:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf |
  Foreach-Object {
    # File item variable is $_
    Write-Host "Printing: $($_.Name)"
    #Open the file with a print command.
    Start-Process -FilePath $_.FullName -Verb Print
  }
```

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: What tool are you using to print pdfs? When I use Adobe Reader, it closes itself after printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience with this but was curious about the Start-Process cmdlet with print verb.  I Googled that and came up with this that looks to be a good solution to your problem:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $.FullName -Verb Print -PassThru | %{sleep 10;$_} | kill
```

Source: http://gregcaporale.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/powershell-to-print-files-automatically/

Comment: So I left the print flag and piped to `stop-process` my `excel` file, but no success.